# How to transfer money from India to USA without attracting penalties

Tags: india, money-transfer

My Father is Indian citizen and I am a resident alien. If my father wants to send me money through bank to bank transfer, what is the limit and what are the latest tax and money transfer laws both in USA and India? I want to make sure I am doing this without attracting penalties on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell your father to visit the bank and ask them to initiate an international transfer. They would convert the Rupees into USD and transfer. There is also a fee for the transfer of around Rs. 1,000 to Rs. 1,500.

If your father has an account with large Government Banks or leading Private Banks, it should be quite simple by approaching the bank.

I've been sending money to my son doing his majors in the US through Remit Now. It's a secure online Foreign Outward Remittance platform provided by HDFC Bank. Sending foreign outward remittance is now as easy as transferring funds via RTGS/NEFT.

All you have to do is Add a Beneficiary > Select Funds Transfer > Input the amount to be transferred > Accept the T&C > Confirm the details

That's it.